# Have to click on an list item 2 times to fire jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input and when someone types in the input I want a list to appear.

Then when someone clicks on a list item I want the list to disappear. But the problem at the moment is I need to click on a list item 2 times for the list to disappear.

This is the html:

```
<input class="my-input" type="text">
```

and here is the jQuery:

```
//when something is typed in the input show a list of items below
$('body').on('keyup change', '.my-input', function() {

  $('#dynamic-search-results').remove();

  var listItems = '<li>Hello</li>';
  listItems += '<li>Awesome</li>';
  listItems += '<li>World</li>';

  $( '<ul id="dynamic-search-results">'+listItems+'</ul>' ).insertAfter( this );

});

//when an item is clicked remove the list
$('body').on( 'mousedown', '#dynamic-search-results li', function() {
   console.log($(this).text());
   $('#dynamic-search-results').remove();
});
```

Why is this not working? Thanks so much for your help in advance.
https://jsfiddle.net/uwkr2yas/1/

Comment: use click instead of mousedown

Comment: Hi guradio, that does not work. This is something I tried previously.

Comment: Actually you binded 2 events in group "keyup change" remove change will work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the change event
 in input .Because first time click in `li`.The change function of input was readded the `ul`

https://jsfiddle.net/prasanth1036/ausj3ng7/5/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    //when something is typed in the input show a list of items below
  $('body').on('keyup', '.my-input', function() {

      $('#dynamic-search-results').remove();

      var listItems = '<li>Hello</li>';
       listItems += '<li>Awesome</li>';
       listItems += '<li>World</li>';

        $( '<ul id="dynamic-search-results">'+listItems+'</ul>' ).insertAfter( this );

  });

  //when an item is clicked remove the list
  $('body').on( 'mousedown', '#dynamic-search-results li', function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
    $('#dynamic-search-results').remove();
  });




});
```

Answer (score 0):

remove change listener from a listener.

The issue is adding ul when you click on li so it will add new ul and li in dom so you need to click two times to remove ul from dom

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    //when something is typed in the input show a list of items below
  $('body').on('keyup', '.my-input', function() {

      $('#dynamic-search-results').remove();

      var listItems = '<li>Hello</li>';
       listItems += '<li>Awesome</li>';
       listItems += '<li>World</li>';

        $( '<ul id="dynamic-search-results">'+listItems+'</ul>' ).insertAfter( this );

  });

  //when an item is clicked remove the list
  $('body').on( 'mousedown', '#dynamic-search-results li', function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
    $('#dynamic-search-results').remove();
  });




});
```

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1cxpjkeq/) for same.